# ionic cordova build is showing lint warnings

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to build APK file with IONIC. I'm following all the tutorials and everything was OK until I tried to build APK with this command:

```
$ ionic cordova build --release android
```

and show me this error:

```
 $ ionic cordova build --release android
    Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova
    [22:57:28]  build dev started ...
    [22:57:28]  clean started ...
    [22:57:28]  clean finished in 9 ms
    [22:57:28]  copy started ...
    [22:57:30]  deeplinks started ...
    [22:57:31]  deeplinks finished in 416 ms
    [22:57:31]  transpile started ...
    [22:57:38]  transpile finished in 7.50 s
    [22:57:38]  preprocess started ...
    [22:57:38]  preprocess finished in less than 1 ms
    [22:57:38]  webpack started ...
    [22:57:40]  copy finished in 11.79 s
    [22:57:57]  webpack finished in 18.34 s
    [22:57:57]  sass started ...
    [22:57:59]  sass finished in 2.21 s
    [22:57:59]  postprocess started ...
    [22:57:59]  postprocess finished in 17 ms
    [22:57:59]  lint started ...
    [22:57:59]  build dev finished in 30.98 s
    > cordova build android --release

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
Android Studio project detected

(node:7784) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'variables' of undefined
(node:7784) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[22:58:05]  tslint: ...der (8)/App Source Code/App Source Code/src/providers/shared-data/shared-data.ts, line: 71
            Property 'push' is declared but never used.

      L70:  public events: Events,
      L71:  private push: Push,
      L72:  public platform: Platform,

[22:58:05]  tslint: ...der (8)/App Source Code/App Source Code/src/providers/shared-data/shared-data.ts, line: 8
            'PushObject' is declared but never used.

       L7:  import { LoadingProvider } from '../loading/loading';
       L8:  import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions } from '@ionic-native/push';
       L9:  import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';

[22:58:05]  tslint: ...der (8)/App Source Code/App Source Code/src/providers/shared-data/shared-data.ts, line: 8
            'PushOptions' is declared but never used.

       L7:  import { LoadingProvider } from '../loading/loading';
       L8:  import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions } from '@ionic-native/push';
       L9:  import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';

[22:58:05]  tslint: ...der (8)/App Source Code/App Source Code/src/providers/shared-data/shared-data.ts, line: 10
            All imports are unused.

       L9:  import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';
      L10:  import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook';
      L11:  import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm';

[22:58:05]  tslint: ...zm/Desktop/New folder (8)/App Source Code/App Source Code/src/pages/cart/cart.ts, line: 44
            Property 'storage' is declared but never used.

      L43:  public toast: Toast,
      L44:  private storage: Storage,
      L45:  public events: Events,

[22:58:05]  tslint: ...op/New folder (8)/App Source Code/App Source Code/src/pages/products/products.ts, line: 8
            All imports are unused.

       L7:  import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
       L8:  import { share } from 'rxjs/operator/share';
       L9:  import { CartPage } from '../cart/cart';

[22:58:05]  lint finished in 6.59 s
```

Answer (score 0):

Building your Application is different than serving it. It's more restrictive cause your App needs to respect the norms of the platform you're targeting.
So you have to correct the mistakes you're seeing in the logs (like deleting some variables or imports you're not using for example:

```
   `import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';`
```

**Edit:**
you Have unused imports. Though it's not an Error, it's a mistake. So when building your app you shouldn't do that.
Also you have some unused private variables So delete them please. 
**Just read the logs you'll know the location of the mistakes & what to remove.**

Comment: what do you mean: So you either have to correct the mistakes you're seeing in the logs (like deleting some variables or imports you're not using - i write to you the code how to correct the mistakes ??

Comment: and when i delete this codes show me errorYou have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
Android Studio project detected
(node:9804) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'variables' of undefined
(node:9804) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[01:23:06]  lint finished in 69.58 s

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that. Somewhere in your code you have an undefined object & you're trying to access variables of that undefined object. I can't help you here you need to study your code again. This is why testing is strongly recommended for mid/big applications.